# Modify dynamically generated li elements with jQuery when dblclicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a simple To Do list that when a new ToDo is generated it creates and appends a new `li` element into a preexisting `ul`. I have a `toggleAll()`function that adds a class which strikes through the `li` elements when double clicked. What I want to do now is to create a method that makes it so when I double click an `li` element, it toggles the line-through class just for the element clicked, so I can mark individual ToDos as completed. I tried using regular JS and jQuery but couldn't find the way to do it with either.

My ToDos are composed of a text property and a boolean determining whether the task is completed or not. Toggling sets the boolean to `true`, and if the boolean is `true`, then the `.marked` class is added to the content of the `li` element.

```js
addTodo: function(todo){
                this.list.push({
                    todoText: todo,
                    completed: false,
                });
                console.log(this.list);
            },


var view = {
            display: function(){
                var printed = document.getElementById('printedList');
                printed.innerHTML = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < todos.list.length; i++){
                    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
                    newLi.innerHTML = todos.list[i].todoText;
                    printed.appendChild(newLi);
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
 .marked{
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }
```

```html
<div id='listica'>
    <ul id='printedList'></ul>
</div>
```

Edit: toggleAll function:

```js
toggleAll: function(){
                var printedElements = document.getElementById('printedList');
                for(var i = 0; i < todos.list.length; i++){
                    if(todos.list[i].completed == false){
                        todos.list[i].completed = true;
                        printedElements.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
                    } else if(todos.list[i].completed == true){
                        todos.list[i].completed = false;
                        printedElements.style.textDecoration = '';
                    }
                };
```

Comment: What does your `toggleAll`  function look like? And what have you tried for the function? Also is addTodo in an object?

Comment: @SimplyComplexable I tried using .addEventListener but that didn't work. I then tried the jQuery .on() method, but that toggled all of the `li` elements within the `ul`, not just the one I was clicking. And yes, addTodo is in an object where I also have a method to remove ToDos and another one to modify ToDos. I also have another object called `handlers` which links DOM functionality with the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.addEventListener()` or jQuery's `.on()`.

With `.addEventListener` you need to loop through all of the `li`s:

```
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.foreach(function(li) {
    li.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
        e.target.classList.add('line-through');
    });
});
```

For `.on()` you don't have to loop through the elements.

```
$('li').on('dblclick', function(e) {
    $(e.target).addClass('line-through');
});
```

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) 
[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) 
[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) 
[`NodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
[`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: I tried this code as is but it didn't work initially. I ended up trying a few different things before I changed the `$('li')` for `$('ul')` which does work for selecting the individual `li` elements. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Sorry for the issues, I must have misunderstood the situation.